# Why replacing malloc causes segment error (__GI__IO_file_overflow)

Tags: c, gdb, malloc

I tried to mimic the way jemalloc replaces ptmalloc by replacing malloc myself, and the replacement resulted in a direct segment error
code1.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void *ptr = malloc(10);
    printf("%p\n", ptr);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

code2.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    return (void *)10;
}
```

Compile instructions

```
gcc -c code2.c
ar r libcode2.a code2.o
gcc code1.c -L. -lcode2 -g
```

gdb

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe318) at code1.c
17      void *ptr = malloc(10);
(gdb) s
18      printf("%p\n", ptr);
(gdb) p ptr
$1 = (void *) 0xa
(gdb) n
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7e46658 in __GI__IO_file_overflow () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Comment: libc itself uses malloc. So it's probably calling your version which is returning a junk pointer. Put a breakpoint on your malloc to verify whether that is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the replacement resulted in a direct segment error code1.c

If you replace `malloc` with a non-functional variant, you better not call any `libc` functions which may use `malloc` in their implementation.

Here you called `printf`, which itself uses `malloc` internally. Use GDB `where` command to observe where the crash happened.

I am actually surprised your program made it as far as reaching `main()` -- I expected it to crash much earlier (there are 1000s of instruction executed long before `main` is reached).